# How come I need to completely restart my server whenever changing Laravel settings?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Nowhere on the internet have I seen anyone have this issue, but I pretty much can't change or add any config/package/vendor without restarting my entire Linux server.

Some simple examples:

- For Intervention image, I set the driver to Imagick in `config/image`, in the controller itself `Image::configure(['driver' => 'imagick'])`, AND in the vendor file itself (`/vendor/intervention/image/src/...`). No matter what, it continued to try to use GD until I restarted the entire server.
- I installed the CloudConvert package with Composer, and added it to `providers` and `facades`. Nothing at all worked until a total reboot.

Before anyone asks, I've tried:

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan config:cache`
- deleting the whole cache folder
- `composer dump-autoload`
- `composer install`
- `composer update`

All of the above did nothing at all. I still need to reboot everything. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: what about `php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache` ?

Comment: btw cache:clear is different from config:clear

Comment: How did you configure the web server and php? Do you have opcache enabled?

Comment: It sounds like you have either PHP or Apache/Nginx caching something. Check their configuration for relevant settings.

Comment: It's just a standard 'Amazon Linux 2' instance - it may have opcache enabled. I'll take a look now. Cheers!